# como puedo cargar 16000 registros a un select o a un input en Angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs

tengo una situacion soy nuevo en angularjs, tengo que cargar una tabla de 16000 registros en un select, pero se que es mucho para que se muestre en un select alguien tiene una sugerencia?tengo que entregarlo pronto u.u

mi codigo html con el init traigo los 16000 registros pero no tengo idea de como cargarlos ya que se debe seleccionar alguno de ellos:S help

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-init="GetArticulos()">
                        <label>Sku Final</label>
                        <br />

                        <input type="search"class="form-control" placeholder="Coloca el codigo de producto" ng-model="searchtext"/>
                        <select ng-model="articuloseleccionado" class="form-control"  data-content="Seleccione un articulo" placeholder="Seleccione un articulo">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione un Articulo</option>
                            <option ng-repeat="articulo in articulos | filter:searchtext" value="">{{tamano.ListaProductos}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

### Código angularjs

#### controlador

```
$scope.articulos = {};
    $scope.GetArticulos = function () {
        console.log("Entrando al  controlador GetPrecios")
        ArticulosService.GetArticulos()
            .then(function (response) {

                if (response.code = 100) {

                    $scope.articulos = response.data.Result;
                    //$scope.tamanos = angular.toJson(response.data.Result);
                    $scope.apply;
                    console.log($scope.articulos);
                }
            }, function (err) { });


    }
```

#### Servicio angular

```
'use strict'
app.service('ArticulosService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    this.GetArticulos = function () {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        console.log("Entrando al Servicio TipoEtiqueta")
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'Labels/ObtenerArticulos',
            // dataType:'json',
            //params:{Itemcode:itemcode}
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                defered.resolve(response);
            },
            function (err) {
                defered.reject(err);
            });

        return defered.promise;

    }
}]);
```

#### Clase c

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult ObtenerArticulos()
        {
            CentralPOSDataManager Code = new CentralPOSDataManager();
            var result = Code.Busqueda_Articulos();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

#### función c

```
 public MethodResponse<List<Articulos>> Busqueda_Articulos()
        {
            MethodResponse<List<Articulos>> Result = new MethodResponse<List<Articulos>>() { Code = 100, Message = "", Result = new List<Articulos>() };
            try
            {
                using (CNTEntities db = new CNTEntities())
                {
                    try
                    {

                        string query = "EXEC Busqueda_Articulos";
                        var res = db.Database.SqlQuery<Articulos>(query).ToList();
                        if (res.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Result.Result = res;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Result.Message = "No encontro registro";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Result.Message = ex.Message + "QUERY DE ETIQUETAS";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Result.Message = ex.Message + "METODO RESPONDE DE ETIQUETAS";
            }
            return Result;
        }
```

#### Store SQL

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Busqueda_Articulos]
 as
  begin 
    SELECT  ItemCode + ' ' + ItemName AS ListaProductos 
        FROM    OITM WITH(NOLOCK)
    ORDER BY ItemCode ASC;
 end
```

alguien que me ayude?

Comment: 16000 registros!!! Definitvamente los select no se hicieron para soportar tanta información; yo creo que pasa por un tema de creatividad... podrías para empezar traer esos registros y encasillarlos en algun tipo de selectlist y poner un input que busque coincidencias no? Sería mucho más efectivo :)

Comment: Mi consejo: usar algo como [select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

Comment: si creo que es imposible, cres que con un like en el store para que deisminuya los registros se pueda cargar? sabes como puedo mandar parametros desde angularjs en base al codigo que seleccione?

Comment: Los artículos tienen **categorías**? Porque si es así, podrías primero filtrar por categoría y en base a esa selección traer los artículos correspondientes, pero insisto que el hecho de traer 16000 registros inicialmente es un poco anómalo =/ .. Esto podría servirte http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/demo-minimum

Comment: son dos columnas, pero las concateno y las llamo como Lista produtos,

Comment: ya le agrege un like en el store y me trae como 16 registros, creo es algo mas fiable, ahora la pregunta es como puedo mandar el dato que capturo en el input como para metro a la consulta

Comment: Imagino que esos 16000 registros son únicos no? Porque si hay registros repetidos sólo te faltaría agregar un `GROUP BY`.. **me extraña que de 16000 registros haya bajado 16**

Comment: si es que como vienen por codigos el parametro que mandare sera apartir de 3 digitos, por ejemplo traeme todos lo que comiencen con 100, y por eos disminuyo tanto

Comment: Bueno si te sirve la solución del `LIKE` bien! En cuanto a rescatar el parámetro del objeto seleccionado, con la librería que te adjunte un poco más arriba no tendrías problema en enviarlo al `controller` de Angular =)